# Were cities that enacted lockdowns during the 1918 flu pandemic successful in preventing any infections?

Tags: public-health, spanish-flu, epidemics

Many parallels are currently being drawn between the flu pandemic of 1918 and the modern spread of the coronavirus, including how a [lockdown was imposed](https://www.seattletimes.com/seattle-news/as-coronavirus-spreads-in-2020-heres-how-seattle-handled-the-1918-flu-that-killed-1513/) in many cities:

> It happened a century ago, too.
>
> On Oct. 5, 1918, Seattle Mayor Ole Hanson made a stunning
>   announcement.
>
> He ordered “every place of indoor public assemblage in Seattle,
>   including schools, theatres, motion picture houses, churches and dance
>   halls closed by noon” that day, [a Seattle Daily Times story said](https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/6795662-Flu-Front-Page-Oct-5-1918.html).

But what was the purpose of these lockdowns? Medicine was rudimentary and couldn't do much to help against viral infections - not that we're much more effective in 2020, given our struggles with COVID-19. Attempts [were made](https://www.historyofvaccines.org/content/blog/vaccine-development-spanish-flu) to develop vaccine, but authorities weren't able to produce enough injections to inoculate the entire population. Contact tracing would've been impossible given the lack of available tests. Given the above, is it known if the lockdown of 1918 was actually effective or did every American eventually become ill with the novel flu regardless of the lockdowns?

Comment: Yes, they were. I recently saw a documentary about it, but haven't bookmarked it.

Comment: lack of basic research around plague law and history

Answer (score 8):

Denver, Colorado is a good sample of the results when the measures start early, but are revoked too soon.

The goal of the lockdown is to prevent people meeting and **transferring** the virus on to others.

When started early, less people are effected and don't pass it on.

On Armistice Day (1918-11-11), people gathered together to celebrate with the result that the virus was passed on to others.

During the next 11 days, those newly infected, passed it on to others until the measures were reinstated.

This is the effect when such measures start too late. More people are affected and they in turn pass it on to others.

Had the measures not have been revoked, the second 'hump' would not have occurred (the effected people on the 11th would not have passed it on had they remained isolated) .

- 1918-09-27: first death
- 1918-10-06: first bans

  - 1918-10-15: 1.440 cases
  - 1918-11-11: removed, including face masks

    - 1918-11-18: 100 cases daily
  - 1918-11-22: reinstated (25th face masks)

    - 6000 cases, 500 deaths
    - 1918-11-27: 438 new cases, 17 deaths
- 1918-12-31: 12.718 influenza cases, 1.218 deaths

[image: Denver double hump]

---

St. Louis also imposed restrictions but did not revoke them for Armistice day: no second hump for that period. 
The restrictions were lifted on the 20th of December and reimposed 1 month later.

Philadelphia imposed no restrictions, which together with a higher, denser population caused the highest numbers of the US cities.

San Francisco, which was spared the first wave of spring of 1918, was aware of the problem but only reacted after the first cases became noticeable.

Deaths per 100.000 (above the expected usual death rate):

- New York 452
- St. Louis 356
- Denver 631
- San Francisco 672
- Philadelphia 748

[image]

- See **[How they flattened the curve during the 1918 Spanish Flu](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/history/2020/03/how-cities-flattened-curve-1918-spanish-flu-pandemic-coronavirus/)** with English text description

  - and 37 other US cities

---

2020-04-29: 10 days into a relaxed shutdown

- Active cases: 21.46% of total cases (6 weeks into lockdown)

  - 2020-04-06: 70.49% of total cases (3 weeks into lockdown)

A major difference to 1918 is that a social distance and encouraged usage of face masks requirements are still in place.

[image: Germany, 2020-04-30]

---

**Sources**:

- [Denver, Colorado and the 1918-1919 Influenza Epidemic | The American Influenza Epidemic of 1918: A Digital Encyclopedia](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/f/flu/cities/city-denver.html#)
- [The Flu in San Francisco | American Experience | Official Site | PBS](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/americanexperience/features/influenza-san-francisco/)
- [How they flattened the curve during the 1918 Spanish Flu](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/history/2020/03/how-cities-flattened-curve-1918-spanish-flu-pandemic-coronavirus/)

Comment: But... how could the Spanish flu have possibly died out without reaching herd immunity? Did the US really eliminate it altogether? Didn't the cities that imposed a lockdown see an equivalent number of deaths, but over a longer period of time?

Comment: @JonathanReez There were reoccurring waves during the early 1920's (worldwide). Research results around the 2000's suggest that the virus mutated into a less deadly form. Unfortunately at that time collection of research data was neglected, so proper conclusions today are difficult.

Comment: @JonathanReez - When the R0 is less than one, an infection will peter out.  Some cities took social distancing measures that reduced R0 enough (at least in the summer months, when flu transmits less readily) that the infection stopped before herd immunity.  Philadelphia got herd immunity quickly, but at a terrible death toll.

Comment: @antlersoft but people still traveled between US cities in 1918. Granted not as quickly as we do now, but they already had cars at the time. So any infection hotspot would've continued on to reinfect the rest of the country no matter what, ensuring a similar final death toll across the entire country, given that medical intervention was non existent, as far as I understand.

Comment: @JonathanReez You're missing the point that the virus continued to mutate.  The deadly 1918 virus mutated into a less deadly virus.  So yes, you're right that it did continue to move around - but the less deadly form "won" against the more deadly form (as tends to be true with viruses - more deadly forms tend to lose out to less deadly forms, as the R0 of the more deadly ones is lower).  The R0 also decreases as more people have it - even if you don't have full herd immunity, even 10% of the population having had it is signifciant.

Comment: @Joe did it mutate into a less deadly version in just a year?

Comment: @JonathanReez We know that the Spanish Flu was  not a big topic in the 20's, depite some  flu waves. In the 1930's interest rose and more research was being done  and data collected that was not done in the early 20's. So reliable data does not exist to say for sure. That at least is what  I have understood from essay's written in the last 20-30 years.

Comment: @JonathanReez Basically - yes.  Influenza mutates *all the time*; hence why it's still a common virus, for the most part, despite our (relatively effective) vaccines - certainly effective enough that if it didn't mutate constantly, it would be a non-issue on the level of measles.  Every year you get significant differences.  Even during that second, high mortality wave, you'd have significant variable strains going around - and the lower mortality ones would have a higher R0.

Comment: @Joe but that's just speculation, right? Wouldn't the default position be that the 1918 flu infected 80+% of Americans, meaning that all restrictions in 1918 were futile?

Comment: @JonathanReez No and it was not futile. More lived to tell the tale. Take the present NY situation. In the long term (next 2-3 years) 80+ will be infected. The present death count of 24.069 (1st May 2020) would have been **much**  higher had there been no restrictions.  With the restrictions the healt services just managed to keep this under control. Without the restrictions the health services would have collapsed. A radical difference, since the health services can deal with newly, lower amount, of infections.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yes, Mark, I agree about 2020. But my question was about 1918 - did their restrictions have any practical benefit in the end, given their primitive medical system and impossibility of contact tracing?

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes they did, since the restrictions **avoided** new infections. The St. Louis / Denver / Philadelphia (full / partial / no restrictions) show that. Then (as now) no vaccine existed, so the goal is to keep the numbers of new infections low so that they are manageable. With contact tracing (where implemented)  the new infections rate will be lower than in 1918/9 and with today's medical capabilities the death rate of the infected will be lower. So there are similarities, but also differences.

Comment: @MarkJohnson but how do we know that the total number of deaths in Denver per capita wasn't exactly equal to the total number of deaths in other major cities? As for managing the disease - did medicine in 1918 actually save anyone? As in, did mortality increase in cities where there were too many patients? That's non-trivial to confirm in 2020, but do we know if Spanish flu treatments had any effectiveness whatsoever in 1918?

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes, the numbers are known. Added a link that shows the numbers (and graphs) for 37 US cities. The medical treatment was basically (I assume) the treatment of symptoms based on previous experiences, since the cause (new virus) was unknown. More reason to keep the infected numbers low when possible.