# Is there a source for excess death statistics in individual cities during the 1918 flu pandemic?

Tags: united-states, spanish-flu

Is there a reliable source for excess deaths in US cities/counties/states around the time of the 1918 flu pandemic? I was able to find [one datasource](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5911181/) for Arizona and [one for NYC](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamanetworkopen/fullarticle/2769236) but nothing specific for other regions. It would ideally have excess deaths data for the years 1910-1930 or even earlier than that.

Related question (now closed): [Were cities that enacted lockdowns during the 1918 flu pandemic successful in preventing any infections?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/58927/were-cities-that-enacted-lockdowns-during-the-1918-flu-pandemic-successful-in-pr)

Comment: @LаngLаngС updated to avoid extraneous discussions. I'm only interested in the raw numbers as the opinions I'm seeing online about NPIs during the flu pandemic seem to be counter-intuitive.

Comment: You could look at the sources listed in John Barry's The Great Influenza.  He repeatedly gives examples of where city (or state) A "did better" than city (or state) B, so I assume he had to look those up somewhere - it seems meticulously researched.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica doing the research now, including reading the book. I’m hoping to gather enough evidence to throughly debunk (or confirm) the “cities which locked down in 1918 saved lives” theory.

Comment: Be warned, "restrictions good" is definitely Barry's take on things.  I assume his sources will support that theory.  Also, I read this for SARS '03, didn't re-read for covid so I'd be hard put to vouch for the quality of his research.  Still, he seems like a solid author on this book.